# Prevent Bleichenbacher by adjusting Padding

Tags: padding, padding-oracle

I got the following question and I really don‘t know how to answer them. My I ask you for your input?

Do you think, that the following adjusted Padding will prevent the classic Bleichenbacher attack

`2Byte Random prefix | Random padding bytes unequal 0xff | 0xff | PremasterSecret`

In theory I would agree (at least for the classic Bleichenbacher), but wouldn‘t that be to easy? And what other problems could come with this coding?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The devil lies in the details. How would the `2Byte Random prefix` and first bytes of the `Random padding bytes unequal 0xff` be chosen to insure that the padded message is less than the public modulus? Or is that chosen with 0xffffff in the high-order 24 bits, which would ensure that?